# Downgrade Cakephp from latest version to 1.3.15

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to downgrade a Cakephp project from latest version to 1.3.15 so it could work on my current server setup, I don't want to upgrade my PHP version because I don't want to screw with my server design, security and infrastructure besides I have a lot of projects on the same server which were designed to work with this exact PHP version, I am a total Cakephp noob but I am working with CodeIgniter, any ideas ?

Comment: You'll have to update PHP eventually.... are we talking PHP 4 here? That is long, long out of date and isn't getting even security patches any more so you should absolutely add PHP 5 to the equation at least for new projects. And apart from that, do you have a specific question?

Comment: NO! I am using php 5.1.6 and yes I am getting errors which eventually cause WSOD because Cake is asking for classes found only in php 5.2

Comment: Depending on the size of your app... you may have your work cut out for you. There is no simple script to downgrade all of your code in the app. best you can do is find the core `cake` in your app and replace it with 1.3.15 and then start combing for errors. Your best bet is to move it to an up to date server setup. You will eventually have to upgrade for security purposes.

Comment: Combing it is, thanks @LetterSticker for your help :))

Comment: What kind of issues do these old apps have? To be honest the code of them must suck if it breaks totally from 5.1 to 5.2. There should be nothing that can't be fixed within minutes if not these apps are bad designed.

Comment: "I don't want to upgrade my PHP version because I don't want to screw with my [...] security" - this statement is quite a paradox.

Comment: "I don't want to screw with my server design, security and infrastructure" you misunderstood me, my applications works perfectly under any PHP version, it's only the way the server was designed at the infrastructure level, I am just lazy to fix all the broken custom bash scripts which are integrated right into php, I hope you gets me good this time :-$